# How to set Event inside TextBlock using MVVM logic?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

below is my code of View part. What I need is want to fire a function call of ViewModel while clicking in TextBlock. As I want to maintain MVVM, I can't use back-end coding of View using sender arguments. I am unaware about Triggers/EventToCommand, please guide me.

**VehicalForm.xaml**

```
        <Window x:Class="Seris.VehicalForm"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">
<Control>
    <Control.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 " >
                <Label Content="Vehical No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicalNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Name="Model_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Model, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Label Content="Manufacturing Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <DatePicker Name="ManufacturingDate_DateTime" SelectedDate="{Binding ManufacturingDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="136"/>
                <Label Content="IU No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBox Height="23" Width="80" Name="IUNO_Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IUNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Content="Personnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ComboBox Name="Personnel_Combo" SelectedValue="{Binding PersonnelNameSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonnelName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="126"/>
                <Separator Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="16"/>
                <Button Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding SaveButton_Command}" Content="Save" Width="66"/>
                <Label x:Name="Error_Label" Content="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Width="137"/>
                <ListView Name ="Grid" Height="294" Width="371" >
                    <DataGrid Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="Cell" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderThickness="0">

                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vehical No">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding VehicalNo}" MouseDown="{Binding Edit_VehicalNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            //Here I want to put//
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Model" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IUNo" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IUNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PersonnelNameSelected" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonnelNameSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>
                </ListView>
                <TextBlock Name="Notification" Text="{Binding EditText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Name="AllowEdit_Text"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver , ElementName=VV}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Text" TargetName="Notification" Value="Kaypo 6e"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Template>
</Control>
</Window>
```

Comment: why cant you use events?, MVVM does not mean no code behind, if it is UI logic then code behind is fine, perhaps an understanding of MVVM will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx

Comment: Then how to get access of other controls (TextBox etc)  from back-end of View?

Comment: Usually you bind the properties of the controls (like textboxes) to fields in your viewmodel. Then you can use those fields to work with the values. Be sure to activate two way binding

Comment: use interaction behavior